# RxSwift Observable race condition

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I have an object created from  `flatMap`ing an observable.

```swift
private lazy var childObj: chilView? = {

    let keychainStore = Realm().getStore()

    let selectedElementID = keychainStore.elementID
        .asObservable()
        .distinctUntilChanged {$0 == $1}
        .flatMap({ (elementID) -> Observable<Element?> in
            guard let elementID = elementID else {
                return Observable.error(Errors.InvalidElementID)
            }

            return Observable.create { observer in
                let elementStream: Observable<Result<Element>> = keychainStore.getObservable(id: elementID)
                elementStream.subscribe(onNext: { (result) in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let element):
                        observer.onNext(element)
                    default: break
                    }
                })
                .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

                return Disposables.create()
            }
        })

    return self.createChildObject(with: selectedElementID)
}()
```

The selectedElement is of type flatMap observable. `createChildObject(with:)` is called even before `observer.onNext(element)` is executed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what kind of object `elementID` is, but if you can do `{ $0 == $1 }`, it conforms to Equatable, which means you can just write `.distinctUntilChanged()` and omit the equality closure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand your problem from the description but here are some thoughts:

It's not a race condition. Your `selectedElementID` chain and the `flatMap` code within it will not be executed before you `subscribe` to the `selectedElementID`. So I guess you subscribe to the `selectedElementID` somewhere within `createChildObject` method and obviously get the `createChildObject` code executed before the `selectedElementID` chain.

Depending on how `keychainStore` rx calls are designed and how you subscribe to `selectedElementID` observable you might get a race condition but I am not sure that the using `RxSwift` is a good decision in this case. Try making your chains more atomic.